# Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token if

Tags: javascript

```
if (fname == null || fname == "") {
```

Getting "uncaught syntax error:unexpected token if in line 13". It says     "SyntaxError: missing variable name" in Javascript lint

```
function validateregistration() {

    var emailRegex = /^[A-Za-z0-9._]*\@[A-Za-z]*\.[A-Za-z]{2,5}$/;    
    var fname = document.form.user_firstname.value,
        lname = document.form.user_lastname.value,
        uname = document.form.username.value,
        femail = document.form.email.value,
        freemail = document.form.verify_email.value,
        fpassword = document.form.password.value,


        if (fname == null || fname == "") {
            document.form.user_firstname.focus();
            document.getElementById("errorBox")
                .innerHTML = "enter the first name";
            return false;
        }
    if (lname == null || lname == "") {
        document.form.user_lastname.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox")
            .innerHTML = "enter the last name";
        return false;
    }

    if (femail == null || femail == "") {
        document.form.email.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox")
            .innerHTML = "enter the email";
        return false;
    } else if (!emailRegex.test(femail)) {
        document.form.Email.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox")
            .innerHTML = "enter the valid email";
        return false;
    }

    if (freemail == null || freemail == "") {
        document.form.verify_email.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox")
            .innerHTML = "Re-enter the email";
        return false;
    } else if (!emailRegex.test(freemail)) {
        document.form.enterEmail.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox")
            .innerHTML = "Re-enter the valid email";
        return false;
    }


    if (fpassword == null || fpassword == "") {
        document.form.password.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox")
            .innerHTML = "enter the password";
        return false;
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line doesn't properly terminate the `var` statement:

```
fpassword = document.form.password.value,
```

Use a semicolon at the end of the line:

```
fpassword = document.form.password.value;

if (fname == null || fname == "") {
```

Answer (score 0):

the last variable definition (fpassword) is ending with a comma

Answer (score 0):

Change this part:

```
    fpassword = document.form.password.value; // <--


    if (fname == null || fname == "") {
```

Answer (score 0):

variables line not terminated

```
var fname = document.form.user_firstname.value,
        lname = document.form.user_lastname.value,
        uname = document.form.username.value,
        femail = document.form.email.value,
        freemail = document.form.verify_email.value,
        fpassword = document.form.password.value;
```